# Cannot build apk with buildozer

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, buildozer

I've been trying to build an APK for 3 days. I'm very new to Linux in general, and I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcte8vcGMSU
I do everything as he shows it, with the only difference is that I couldn't install kivy the way he did, I installed it in another way but it works and I can run my main.py from the terminal.
Anyway, buildozer init works, but when I try to use buildozer android debug, this error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 567, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 884, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 775, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (buildozer 0.38.dev0 (/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('buildozer==1.2.0.dev0'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/buildozer", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('buildozer==1.2.0.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')())
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1053, in run_command
    targets = [x[0] for x in self.targets()]
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1053, in <listcomp>
    targets = [x[0] for x in self.targets()]
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 944, in targets
    m = __import__('buildozer.targets.{0}'.format(target),
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 41, in <module>
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 657, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 556, in module_from_spec
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 83, in create_module
    return importlib.import_module('setuptools._distutils')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3239, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3222, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3251, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 569, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 582, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/home/rain/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 770, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'buildozer==1.2.0.dev0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I'm sorry I'm new, I'm just really confused and helpless. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Using latest version of Ubuntu in VM.

Answer (score 0):

this might be because you are using python 3.8
try python 3.6 and make sure not only install python3.6 also to change main python version to 3.6

how to install python is easy to find so I won't discuss

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 0
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 0
```

last number 0 is priority, if above not work try 1 or 2

this is how to change main python version

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the GitHub repo for [Buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git), change directory to the /buildozer folder.

Now run `sudo python3 setup.py install`

If you haven't installed setuptools for Python yet, first install them by `sudo apt-get install -y python3-setuptools` and then run the previous command again.

Now you can start converting your projects into APKs.
Make sure the project folder is inside this /buildozer dir.